# How to get contours of multiple images in a folder

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a lot of images in a folder and I am trying to detect the second largest contour in each image in the folder as well as the area and radius of that contour. This is the code I have written but I only get the radius for last image. However, when I print out the contour length I get the length of contours for each image in the folder. Can someone please advice on how to get all the radius of the detected contours in all the images in the folder and also how to display each image.

```
# looping and reading all images in the folder
for fn in glob.glob('E:\mf150414\*.tif'):
    im = cv2.imread(fn)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    second_largest_cnt = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[1:2]
    cv2.drawContours(img,second_largest_cnt,-1,(255,255,255),-1)  

# detecting the area of the second largest contour
for i in second_largest_cnt:
    area = cv2.contourArea(i)*0.264583333    # Area of the detected contour (circle)                                                    
    equi_radius = np.sqrt(area/np.pi)        # radius of the contour
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get the radius of the last image because you re-assign second_largest_cnt every for loop. You need to create an array of `second_largest_cnt` outside the for loop to store the contour. For example:

```
second_largest_cnts = []

for fn in glob.glob('E:\mf150414\*.tif'):
    im = cv2.imread(fn)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    second_largest_cnt = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[1] # don't need slicing
    # store the contour
    second_largest_cnts.append(second_largest_cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(img,[second_largest_cnt],-1,(255,255,255),-1)  

#do the same with radius
radius = []
# detecting the area of the second largest contour
for i in second_largest_cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(i)*0.264583333    # Area of the detected contour (circle)                                                    
    radius.append(np.sqrt(area/np.pi))       # radius of the contour
```